# Preserve previous page when URL is changed manually with $location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser-history

I've got a function in my controller that changes the browser's URL but I need to preserve the real previous page when user clicks on back button.

For example:

User is in /home and navigate to /article1. When user scrolls in the page I change the URL, for example to /article2 using:

```
$location.path('article2');
```

But if the user presses the back browser button staying in /article2 the url change to /article1 and I really need to redirect the navigation to /home.

I've used this code:

```
var previousPage = document.referrer; // Get the previous location on page load
history.pushState({}, '', previousPage); // Alter the history adding the previous page
```

But it doesn't work because in the change of the url using $location, the history state is altered automatically.

How can I preserve the navigation?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this way

```
window.onpopstate = () => history.replaceState(history.state, 'gotohome', '/')
```

it will work but , how can i change url of previous page without using window.onpopstate help me if any one knows

Answer (score 0):

You could also store the previous page locally to go back to. I have an application that has a back button to allow you to go back to the page you had navigated from. Try something like this:

```
sessionStorage.previousPage = "mypage";

function goBack(){
 $location.path(sessionStorage.previousPage);
};
```

Comment: yeah it's a good way to solve it. But the problem is how to intercept the browser back button?

Comment: You can't, and I say that lightly because there is a chance that someone has solved that issue. All browsers are different in the way they handle the back button so it makes it very difficult to do. This is why we came up with the solution above as a work around to the browser back button. Please if you do find a way I would love to know because we can use that in our application.